# Can I get or cast to the underlying GOutputStream from a GDataOutputStream?

Tags: c, glib

I have a `GDataOutputStream*` and now I need to close the underlying `GOutputStream*` manually (by calling `g_output_stream_close()`).

Is it safe to just cast `GDataOutputStream*` to `GOutputStream*`? Or do I need to get the underlying stream some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that’s the right way to do things:

```
g_autoptr(GError) local_error = NULL;
if (!g_output_stream_close (G_OUTPUT_STREAM (my_data_stream), NULL, &local_error))
  {
    /* handle the error, for example: */
    g_warning ("Error closing stream: %s", local_error->message);
  }
```